# Apollo/GraphQL - update cache not updating ROOT_QUERY after mutation

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

Mutation:

```
  const [createContact] = useMutation(CREATE_CONTACT, {
    update(cache, { data: { createContact } }) {
      const { getContacts } = 
        cache.readQuery({
          query: GET_CONTACTS,
          variables: { _id: user._id },
        }
      );
      cache.writeQuery({
        query: GET_CONTACTS,
        variables: { _id: user._id },
        data: [...getContacts, createContact],
      });
    },
  });
```

The mutation works, but it won't update the original query of GET_CONTACTS which is run in the parent component, the result being passed down to this component. I've tried a lot of random things I've seen on here, like using client.writeQuery, using cloneDeep on the readQuery result, and various ways of creating the new data. Still can't figure out what the problem is. Thanks for any help.

Comment: have you tried the way it is in the official docs using `cache.modify`? https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#making-all-other-cache-updates

Comment: `data` is an object, not an array ... if you don't see it ... read entire `data` (w/o destructuring), `console.log` it (to check structure) and prepare a new `data` with new `getContacts` (array?) ... make it one liner later

Comment: @xadm damn that was totally the issue and pretty obvious. Thanks.